# <x> should be a numeric matric or a numeric vector

Tags: r

I am passing xreg (external regressors/independent variables) below to `auto.arima`, and I get the message `xreg should be a numeric matrix or a numeric vector`. I checked for `class(xreg)` and got `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`.  I am just trying to lag A and B, and so I introduce A_lagged and B_lagged as the lagged versions. After I put them in as columns, I remove A and B.

Can someone tell me what could be wrong? Thank you.

```
xreg=Model_Dataset %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        filter(Category==Cat,Date<ForecastDate+weeks(Horizon)) %>%
        select(ExtVariables)%>% 
        mutate('A_lagged',c(249,head(`A`,-1)))%>%
        mutate('B_lagged',c(269,head(`B`,-1)))%>%
        select(-`A`,-`B`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `,` in 'A_lagged', and 'B_lagged'.  It should be replaced with `=`

```
library(dplyr)
Model_Dataset %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(Category==Cat,Date<ForecastDate+weeks(Horizon)) %>%
    select(ExtVariables)%>% 
    mutate('A_lagged' = c(249,head(A,-1)))%>%
    mutate('B_lagged'= c(269,head(B,-1)))%>%
    select(-A,-B)
```

Comment: Why did it not throw an error? Is what I wrote valid syntax that means something else?

Comment: @user2371765  When you do `mutate('A_lagged',c(249,head(`A`,-1)))`, it is selecting two column instead of renaming A_lagged to the value of `c(249,head(`A`,-1))`

Comment: With A_lagged full of NAs?

Comment: @user2371765 Not clear without a small reproducible example (using `dput`)

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense.